# Navigate one screen to another screen based on time period in BlackBerry app

Tags: blackberry, java-me

For my Blackberry application I am using a start up screen with progress bar. I am filling the progress bar using a timer and after the progress bar is complete, I need to navigate to another screen.

I am checking like this, where 'i' is time, increasing from 0 to 100.

```
timer.cancel(); 

if(i>=99) 

UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new TipCalculatorScreen());
```

This code is not working.

For progress bar I am using code like this:

```
 private GaugeField percentGauge;

  percentGauge = new GaugeField(null, 0, 100,50, GaugeField.PERCENT);

                 timer=new Timer();
                   timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask(){
                       int i=0;

                       public void run() {
                           percentGauge.setValue(i);
                              i++;
                                 if(i>=99)
                                 {
                                     timer.cancel();

                                       //for page navigating i am given like this here screen is not navigating getting error
                               UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new nextscreen());   

                                 }       

                           }
                   }, 100,100);
```

Comment: Can you share what isn't working in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make changes to the UI on the UI thread. The TimerTask is executing on its own thread. Instead of

```
UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new nextscreen());
```

you should use

```
UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        UiApplication.getUiApplication()..pushScreen(new nextscreen());
    }
});
```

The update to your gauge control probably needs the same treatment.

Comment: Good to hear :) Here on stackoverflow you can mark an answer as Accepted so others know it's a good answer (and I get credit for it).

Good luck!